# Changing array to textbox qt c++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I have an array or `QString` with size of `100`, and I want to display its contents in to the `QTextBox`, one under another etc. [Image showing my array in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkUiv.jpg)

I tried:

```
QStringList str;
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    str << sortowanie.w_petla[100];
}
ui->text_out1->append(str.join("\n"));
```

but the program crashes.

Comment: `array(QString)` - what kind of syntax is this? Also don't post images that could have been posted as a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most certainly that you should be using `i` to index the array:

```
str << sortowanie.w_petla[i];
```

and not its length. That's access out of range.